# Nested DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm showing alert in a function which I call from VC. I don't want main VC to be blocked. I'm calling this alert function in async. The function in turn has another async. Is this good practice or I'm doing it wrong?

Can anyone suggest good practice for following code?

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Don't block main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.showAlert(title: "Title", message: "Message")
        }

        // Do other stuff ...

    }
}

func showAlert(title: String = "", message: String) {

    alert = UIAlertController(title: title,message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a problem with `DispatchQueue` :)

Your program uses operation queues while running. This queues can be system-defined(like `main`) or user defined. When you use `DispatchQueue.main.async(_:)` you enqueue a code block to main queue. When their time comes, main queue execute them.

But in `viewDidLoad(_:)`, you are already in `main` queue. Also, cause of calling an `AlertController` is a UI operation and UI operations can't be done on any queue except `main`, you don't need to send your code block to any queue and you shouldn't.

And also, Like @SeanRobinson159 said, `AlertController` does not block main thread when it is on screen. It works like your orther `ViewControllers`.

**So, Which cases you should use `DispatchQueue` to call an `AlertController`**

You should use `DispatchQueue.main.async(_:)` to send code blocks that performs UI operations (like calling `AlertController` or changing `UILabel`'s text), to main queue from different queue. For example, maybe you work on an network operation. You make your operation in different thread and when result comes, You can send your code block that makes UI operations, to main queue.

You can google GCD(Grand Central Dispatch) for deatiled information.

Comment: Blunder from my side. My whole concept of dispatch queue was wrong. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Showing an alert doesn't block the thread. `present(_:animated:completion:)` is not a blocking operation, so there's no reason to add any of these `.async` calls.

That said, you wouldn't want to try to present an alert inside `viewDidLoad`. That's far too early. Your view controller isn't on the screen yet. You should put `showAlert()` in `viewDidAppear`, and remove all the `.async` calls.

As a general rule, these kinds of modal alerts should be a last resort in any case, especially when a view controller is coming on screen. Generally, you should integrate whatever message you want to present to the user into the view itself rather than blocking the entire UI. But if an alert is appropriate (and sometimes they are), then you can just present them directly as long as you're on the main queue.

Comment: I want to show alert to user while I continue to do stuff in the main thread. If I don't add it in .async I'll have to wait for user input on alert to continue execution. Isn't it blocking?

Comment: Alerts are modal. That means the user can't do anything while they're presented. What are you trying to do on the main queue while blocking the user?

Answer (score 0):

You should only put what you **have to** on to the main thread. So you shouldn't wrap it in the main.async block in the viewDidLoad function.

You should wrap it in a `DispatchQueue` with a different priority.

i.e. `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { }`

Comment: I want to show alert to user with Ok on it. I don't want to wait for user to click on Ok to continue code execution. How do we do it?

Comment: That isn't how the UIAlertController works. When you add an action to an alert controller, it takes a handler, that is a callback to execute when the action is pressed. It isn't synchronous, so it won't stop the other code execution.